# JQuery change CSS style of table cells which contain disabled elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With JQuery, how can I select and change the CSS style of all text elements inside table cells which contain disabled "input" and/or "select" elements?

I need to iterate over all cells in the table, see if there are any disabled "input" and/or "select" elements in there, and if that is the case, then all text in that particular cell should be "dimmed" by setting its CSS property opacity=0.5.

The solution must work in all reasonably modern browsers.

Comment: include your html and what you've tried

Comment: maybe: `$('td').has(':disabled').css('opacity', .5);`

Comment: You also need to explain precisely what you mean by "*all text elements,*" given that there's no 'text-element' CSS selector; should this affect *all* descendant elements, or *just* the text? What about `<img>` or `<input>` elements?

Comment: In principle indeed it should be everything in the cell -  in my particular case I only need to consider text because that's all I have in there, apart from the elements that may be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [:disabled](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) pseudo-selectors on the TD elements:

```
$('td:has(:disabled)').css('opacity', .5);
```

if you need to be more specific about the disabled elements (probably not needed), use [:input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) too (`:input` covers both select and input):

```
$('td:has(:input:disabled)').css('opacity', .5);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `$('td input:disabled, td select:disabled').css('opacity','0.5');`

Comment: This only changes the class on the input & select. The OP wanted to change all the contents of the `TD`, so the class needs to be applied there.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.